# Solving PyCrypto 2.6.1 errors for Python 3.4 (Windows7 x64)?

Tags: development, windows, python

Whilst there's less of an issue with Python 2.7, Python 3.4 relies on the pycrypto library for numerous wrappers/APIs/tools such as BlockTrail, pycoin, pybitcointools, etc etc.

The error I'm getting:

```
building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension

warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

It's [an issue with the gcc C++ compiler for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829188/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-installing-fabric-python-library-on), I understand, however the binaries offered in that solution, sadly, don't cover Python 3.4 (version for 3.**3** won't cut it, unfortunately).

A solution - other than installing *pseudo-Posix (ie Ming32)* - would be very useful for those transitioning to Python 3.x`enter preformatted text here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Download the package from here. I personally tested this for Python 3.4 and Windows 64 bit.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6rckn0k6u4nqke/pycrypto-2.6.1.zip?dl=0

- Select your architecture and install the exe file.
- This will create a Lib folder in your python directory. My python was
  installed in C:\python3.4. This software created a directory in
  C:\   .The directory was named "Lib".
- Inside lib there is "site-packages".
  Copy everything under site-packages (only two folders - `Crypto` and `*.egg-info`) and then paste where your
  python's site-package is. E.g. I am using virtualenv and my path was
  C:\Users\RChaudhary\Programs\PythonVirtualEnvironment\bookeeping.frontend\Lib\site-packages
- I pasted my files here and voila, it works. pip3.4 list showed my the
  package and my program also runs correctly.
- From your program manager, uninstall what you installed earlier. Your pycrypto will still work.

Comment: ` From your program manager, uninstall...` that's good to know!

Comment: Lol! Sorry about that. I have a habit of cleaning. So I cannot stand having unwanted files on my system.

Comment: I was being serious FWIW

Answer (score 2):

Binaries available for **Python 3.4**:

- https://github.com/axper/python3-pycrypto-windows-installer 32 & 64 bits

As [outlined here on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21829189/3936486), binaries available for **Python 2.x - 3.3**:

- http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

This solves the dependencies issues error `compile failed with error code 1` using pip. Also, the following error screen (at the CLI) should not be appearing any more following installation, via pip or *setup install*, of [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) dependent libraries!

```
Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
running build_ext
building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```